# How to prove the general formula for the Basel problem?

Tags: summation

So I understand Euler's proof of the Basel Problem:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

But how would I prove the general formula? Is it possible to prove without going into complex calculus and Fourier series?

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^{2k}}= \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\pi^{2k}2^{2k}B_{2k}}{2(2k)!}$$

Where $B_k = $ the $k^{th}$ Bernoulli number.

Comment: Did you see this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Cauchy's_proof

Comment: Yes I have, does that prove the general term?

Comment: @mathkid225 read about $\zeta$ function. I guess there are a lot of links here.

Comment: Have a look at pages 59-60 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - Very nice notes! You should consider publishing them as a book.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks for quoting my "smile smugly" line :-)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The notes on Google require special access. Are they still available?